# getAllCellInfo returns null for 2G sims

Tags: android, telephonymanager

If i use [getAllCellInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo()) in a device which contains 2G sim it is returning null (note: API Level: 21). I even tried [getNeighboringCellInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNeighboringCellInfo()) it is returning an empty `List<NeighboringCellInfo>`

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        List<CellInfo> cellInfos = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
        if(cellInfos==null){
            List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellInfos = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
            CellLocation cellLocation = telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

        }
}
```

Note: I have required permissions android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION for `getAllCellInfo` in my manifest file

Comment: Generally we need to see some of your code to understand what's going on. Please prepare an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this inappropriate question. I found that, the issue i mentioned above is not because i am using a 2G sim, it is because I dont have sim in SIM1 Slot. When I am using this code with a 3G sim(Slot 1) and 2G(Slot 2) it worked as I expected then I disabled Slot1 to check for 2G and I got the above problem.

After a while of testing I enabled SIM1 and changed it to 2G, now I am getting expected results. I am writing so that it can help others. Sorry for my English.